# Align vertical button group with text in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to center align a vertical button group with text in bootstrap, in a single div.

I'll will be grateful if someone throws me an idea on how to approach this.

Here are some images illustrating what I mean

Text on one side of button group:

[image: Text on one side of button group]

And on both sides:

[image: And on both sides]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Hi joropicha - can you show us what you have tried so far, and explain in what ways it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Check the example code at [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/EgxQWa?editors=1000)

```
<div class="box">
  <span>First Text</span>
  <div aria-label="Vertical button group" role="group" class="btn-group-vertical"> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
  <span>Second Text</span>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you.
Enjoy :)